# Changing the content of HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code as

```
<td id="myColumn" class="Column">
Old Data
</td>
```

Using a jquery I would like to change the "Old Data" to "My New Data". I try as

```
$( ".Column" ).append("My New Data");
and
$( ".Column" ).replaceWith("My New Data");
```

Comment: If you only want to do that then you can use plain javascript `document.querySelector("#myColumn").innerHTML="My New Data";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As Html:**

```
$( ".Column" ).html("My <strong>New</strong> Data");
```

Outputs: 'my **New** Data'

---

**As String:**

```
$( ".Column" ).text("My <strong>New</strong> Data");
```

Outputs: 'my **New** Data'

---

If you want to replace something in current value, you can use `.html()` as getter:

```
$( ".Column" ).html(  $(".Column").html().replace('old', 'new')  );
```

---

And a plain Javascript method, all credit goes to: [yantrakaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2735314/yantrakaar) (placed it here for a more complete answer)

```
document.querySelector("#myColumn").innerHTML="My New Data"; // Modern browsers
document.getElementyId("myColumn").innerHTML="My New Data"; // Older browsers
```

Comment: the js only method works only if FF>=3.5 || IE>=8. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: Added another jsmethod :) Was thinking about it, but I guess its good to make a note of it

Answer (score 7):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$( ".Column" ).html("My New Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.append` or `.replacewith` please use `.html`.

ex: `$( ".Column" ).html("My New Data");`

Because .append() won't solve your problem, it is also used to append any text with the previous one. It never replaces the previous text.

Comment: This answer has been given twice allready :) Not really addition info this